# Google Maps Polygon Hover - Close InfoWindow on polygon mouseout or infowindow mouseout

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

This seems simple but I can't find a solution. I have a Google Map with KML and polygons. Hovering over polygons brings up an infobox. If the user hovers over the infobox it needs to stay open, but if the user hovers out of the infobox OR if the user mouseouts of the polygon then the infobox should close. So it sounds simple, but at the moment I can only do one or the other.

UPDATE:

The below is working now, however it is a little 'buggy'. This is due to the 'mouseout' function occurring when the user is infact hovering around the center of the polygon (where the infobox pops up) the script thinks they have moved the cursor out of the polygon because the infobox layer loads on top.

Code:

```
// User moves the cursor outside of the active polygon
         google.maps.event.addListener(poly,"mouseout",function() {

             $poly = this;
             $infowindow_hover = false;

             $("#geoxml3_infowindow").mouseenter(function(){
                    clearTimeout($(this).data('timeoutId'));
                    $infowindow_hover = true;

                }).mouseleave(function(){
                    var someElement = $(this),
                        timeoutId = setTimeout(function(){

                                $poly.infoWindow.close();


                        }, 500);
                    //set the timeoutId, allowing us to clear this trigger if the mouse comes back over
                    someElement.data('timeoutId', timeoutId); 
                });

            function closeInfoWindow()
            {
                if ($infowindow_hover == false) $poly.infoWindow.close();
            }

             setTimeout(closeInfoWindow, 1000)

     });
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I have tried but there is so much to consider. I am using geoxml3 among other libraries and custom KML files etc and getting a simple reducted test case working is proving to be a nightmare.

Answer (score 1):

You will nee a delay  before you close the infoWindow.

Observe the mouseover/mouseout-events of the polygon and the content-node of the infowindow.

Set the `$infowindow_open`-variable there and run the function that closes the infoWindow with a short delay, so the user will be able to move the mouse between polygon and infowindow without closing the  infowindow.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Please see the code above - I have tried to implement this but it is buggy. Any further advice?

Comment: I'm afraid there isn't a proper soulution with a InfoWindow, `#geoxml3_infowindow` will only match the contents of the infowindow, but not the margin and the arrow. Unfortunately there is no implemented option to access these elements. It would be possible to traverse the document-tree to find these elements, but this will be buggy too, because there is no guarantee for this structure. A custom implementation like http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/docs/reference.html would be an option, access to the wrapping elements is easier there (and  consistent)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use below code to handle mouseout event over polygon

```
google.maps.event.addListener(poly,"mouseout",function(e) {

    if (infoWindow) {
        infoWindow.close();
    }

});
```

Assuming `var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();` is your info window object.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this isn't a solution for if the infoWindow is being hovered over. Eg. this will close the infowindow as soon as you hover over it because the polygon will be 'mouseout'